# Determining if an std::string contains a numerical type

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, c++14

I recently came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c) asking for methods to determine if a `std::string` represents an integer. There is also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447206/c-isfloat-function) for `float`s. I decided to code up a few methods consolidating these questions.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

namespace detail
{
    const auto is_digit = [] (const char c) { return std::isdigit(c); };
}

bool is_integral(const std::string& str)
{
    return !str.empty() && std::all_of(std::cbegin(str), std::cend(str), detail::is_digit);
}

bool is_floating_point(const std::string& str)
{
    using std::cbegin; using std::cend;

    auto it = std::find_if_not(cbegin(str), cend(str), detail::is_digit);

    return it != cend(str) && *it++ == '.' && std::all_of(it, cend(str), detail::is_digit);
}

bool is_arithmetic(const std::string& str)
{
    using std::cbegin; using std::cend;

    if (str.empty()) return false;

    auto it = std::find_if_not(cbegin(str), cend(str), detail::is_digit);

    return it == cend(str) || (*it++ == '.' && std::all_of(it, cend(str), detail::is_digit));
}
```

Here's an example/expected behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string empty {};
    std::string integer {"123"};
    std::string floating1 {"123."};
    std::string floating2 {"123.4"};
    std::string neither1 {"123..4"};
    std::string neither2 {"1r23"};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << is_integral(empty) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_floating_point(empty) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(empty) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_integral(integer) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << is_floating_point(integer) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(integer) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_integral(floating1) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_floating_point(floating1) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(floating1) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_integral(floating2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_floating_point(floating2) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(floating2) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_integral(neither1) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_floating_point(neither1) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(neither1) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_integral(neither2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_floating_point(neither2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(neither2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_integral(neither2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_floating_point(neither2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << is_arithmetic(neither2) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for any improvements.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: What about hexadecimal integers ?

Comment: oh dear, forgot about negative numbers! I was thinking about hexadecimal, but decided not to in the interest of performance.

Comment: @Daniel Also `std::stoi()`, `std::stod()`, etc. already are available for this functionality.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not quite. They can perform the conversion, but they also have odd behaviour in some cases (e.g. "123foo" will be converted to 123). It will also be less efficient to actually try to do the conversion rather than just a check.

Comment: Seems `is_floating_point` does not handle the float number `1e-2`

Comment: @Daniel The `pos` parameter can be checked how many characters were actually processed.

Answer (score 5):

#### Functional issues

Your code doesn't consider negative numbers to be integral. You're also missing support for things like `1e4` for floating point. Ultimately, `std::stoi` and `std::stof` might be better for your needs:

```
boost::optional<int> convert_integer(std::string const& str) {
    try {
        size_t pos;
        int result = std::stoi(str, &pos);
        if (pos == str.size()) {
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return boost::none;
        }
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& ) {
        return boost::none;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range& ) {
        return boost::none;
    }
}
```

and similar for floating point.

#### `is_digit`

There's no reason for this to be a lambda. It's actually quite a bit shorter if you just write it as a function:

```
const auto is_digit = [] (const char c) { return std::isdigit(c); };
bool is_digit(char c) { return std::isdigit(c); }
```

#### `using std::cbegin;`

There's actually no reason to bring this in, since you could already make an unqualified call to `cbegin()` thanks to ADL. Also, you don't even need `cbegin()` since `begin()` would have done the same thing (`str` is a reference to const in all of your functions).

#### Too much action

This is really busy:

```
return it != cend(str) && *it++ == '.' && std::all_of(it, cend(str), detail::is_digit);
```

And it's confusing since you increment `it` in the middle. Which happens to work, but I had to stop and really think about it to convince myself that it does. You could simply shift the `++` into the `all_of`:

```
return it != cend(str) && 
    *it == '.' && 
    std::all_of(it + 1, cend(str), detail::is_digit);
```

Since there's no modification going on here, each of the 3 parts are easier to reason about.

#### Just `std::string`?

A logical extension would be to change your functions to take iterator pairs, or `const char*` pairs. You could provide convenience string methods to forward to the helpers, but it'd be potentially more useful to have

```
// one of...
bool is_integral(const char* first, const char* last);
template <class It>
bool is_integral(It first, It last);

// ... and a helper to forward
bool is_integral(const std::string& str);
```

Comment: You cheated a bit with the 2 `const` in the lambda vs function length comparison.

Comment: @nwp With the best intentions though!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for strings that may be convertible to `long` would be this:

```
bool is_integral(const std::string& str) {
    bool islong = true;
    try { 
        std::stol(str);
    } catch(...) {
        islong = false;
    }
    return islong;
}
```

For floating point values, there is a corresponding `stod` that will `throw` if the passed string is not convertible.

Comment: This is insufficient and will return true for something like `"1s"`

Comment: @Barry:  Insufficient by what definition?  That is the behavior I would want and expect.  If it *could* be interpreted as a number, return `true`.